# User jquery to replace a word with another universally, but ignore html tags, attributes, script tags, etc

Tags: jquery

I want to replace a word say "strong" with another word "firm" all throughout the dom.
However, I want to ensure this only replaces the text and not inside html tags or script tags..

`<span> He was strong </span>` should be replaced with `<span>He was firm </span>`
but 
`<strong> He was strong </strong>` should not be replaced with `<firm>He was firm </firm>` but instead `<strong> He was firm </strong>`

It should also not replace it inside html attributes or script tags

```
<script>
var strong= 2;
<script>
```

Code

```
   const html = jQuery(document.body).html();


   var re = new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b","g");

   const replaced = html.replace(re, replacement);

   jQuery(document.body).html(replaced);
```

I am thinking of using regex to determine when stuff is inside html, but not sure if this is a good idea.

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

To summarize: Need to replace all instances of a word with another word while not doing so inside script tags, html tags etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try on the below code?`$('*').each(function(index, element) { 
var newtext=$(element).text().replace("strong","firm");
$(element).text(newtext);
});`

Comment: the problem with this appaoach is that it will override the html.

Comment: You can add one more condition to check if it is the last child element. Then do the replace. Else don't do the replace. .text() always give the inner text value between tags